# Need to instantiate an Android activity to pass to another method

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing

I am trying to call this method:

```
   public static void trackFunXStartActivity(Activity a)
{
    s.startFunXActivity(a);
}
```

I'm trying to call it using this code in my LayoutsActivity.java:

```
public void onStart() {
    TrackFunX.trackFunXStartActivity(LayoutsActivity);
}
```

but I'm not sure how to create or reference the Activity that I can pass to trackFunXStartActivity(Activity a). I don't think I can pass LayoutsActivity as an Activity.

How do I go about instantiating or reference an activity in LayoutsActivity.java to pass to trackFunXStartActivity.

I'm a Android newbie and have done some searches on StackOverflow but didn't see anything to help with this questions.

Thanks

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to start an activity? Or are you trying to pass data around? or both?

Comment: I'm trying to pass an 'activity' as an object from the onStart event of LayoutsActivity.java to another method that will use that activity to record the start of the game. Hope this helps.

Comment: "How do I go about instantiating or reference an activity in LayoutsActivity.java to pass to trackFunXStartActivity." -- you don't do that. You do not pass an activity to another activity. You come up with a better system that fits with the loose coupling built into Android's activity model.

Comment: Well I'm trying to pass an activity to a src file with methods. The one I'm passing it to is just a method, not another activity. Does that help?

Comment: what are you trying to do with that activity reference in that method?

Comment: Good question Sharath, it is a third party tool and I'm not quite sure what it is doing other than logging the start of the activity.

Comment: ok well since you need only reference of the activity simply use ClassName.this to pass the reference(Context).

Comment: YOu should not pass the Activity object around. You should try to constrain it to the data inside of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

take a static context for the LayoutsActivity like

```
static Context context;
```

and in the oncreate method use

```
context = LayoutsActivity.this
```

and finally you can use this context in the class where you need